# prevent aynctask getting killed before completion?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

in my activity, i have an asynctask that downloads a series of images...(it may take some time depending on the size of the images)... before i execute the asynctask, i display a progress dialog in `onPreExecute` and a notification (when user clicks on notification it is redirected to my activity with the progress dialog). when my asynctask completes, in `onPostExecute`, i remove the dialog and the notification.. i handle screen orientation by using `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`to save my asynctask so that when screen is rotated, i check if task is still running and i display the progress dialog if it is still running in `onCreate`

Problem : sometimes: my asynctask downloads only 1 file and it seems that it gets killed...(no exception in logcat)... as a result, my notication is always there and my progress dialog also... and they remain there indefinitely....

i have tried the solution by Jeff Axelrod there: [How can I ensure an AsyncTask is completed before my activity is killed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831894/how-can-i-ensure-an-asynctask-is-completed-before-my-activity-is-killed):

```
It looks like if I override the onPause() event in my activity, and from within the overridden onPause(), I call cancel(false) on the AsyncTasks, then the activity is not destroyed until the AsyncTasks are completed.
```

seems to do the trick but problem is that my `onPostExecute` is not called anymore; all images download fine but as `onPostExecute` is not executed, notification and progress dialog still remain there forever.

waiting for your solutions guys! i read use asyntask only for short task; will the use of thread and handler solves my problem? will android kills my activity or thread if the latter is not finished??

Answer (score 2):

Best way how to handle Asynctask is [described in this article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html).

In short, the idea is to keep AsyncTask in fragment with `setRetainInstance(true);` these will keep You AsyncTask alive all time user is in activity holding this fragment and won't be destroyed on configuration change (orientation change).

If You need Your AsyncTask to run after user leaves Activity, for example goes to next Activity but You wish download to continue You should use [services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: thx for this good guide but that still does not explain why my aynctask never completes unless i put `cancel(true);` in my onPause activity event

Comment: Then post Your code so we can examine it. My bad I didn't point it out directly but You shouldn't use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` and use described method instead.